# what isUA-XXXX-YY in window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY') in danwilson/google-analytics-plugin. and from where i will get it

Tags: cross-platform, cordova-plugins, hybrid

i am implementing google analytics in my cordova based hybrid app using danwilson/google-analytics-plugin. here is github link for that plugin 
"https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin"  to implement it 
i will have to write this window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY') in my on device ready but i am not getting what is UA-XXXX-YY over here.and how i will be getting it in my app. any forwarding hand will be greatly appreciated and thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That is the tracking ID which is found on the Google Analytics site. It can be found under any of your projects, then visit the administrator panel. `Admin->Tracking Info->Tracking Code` it's at the top left.

Answer (score 0):

See you have a to create a google analytics account for your app.
You need to fill few details in your analytic account about your app
After the creation you will get the TRACK-ID related to your google account.
This track-id must be placed in your code

```
window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY')
```

where 'UA-XXXX-YY' is the ID you get from the account.

Make sure you place the above code inside device ready of your landing page.